# Does "effusive" have a negative connotation?

Tags: word-usage, connotation

> He was very effusive in his praise of the features.

[The definition on wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/effusive) shows a lot of words that gives me the feeling that *effusive* has a negative connotation:

- unrestrained
- excessive
- extravagant

And the related meaning of a volcanic rock that is pouring heightens that feeling.

Is *effusive* a negative word or can it express positive connotation, too? Does the connotation change if I replace *effusive* with *gushy*?

Comment: *Unrestrained* and *extravagant* are not negative except when context make them so. *Excessive* is the only one of your three synonyms with a built-in criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. *Effusive* is not negative, it has a positive connotation to it. 'He was very effusive in his praise of the features.' is fine.

[**effusive**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/effusive)
*adjective* demonstrative, enthusiastic, lavish, extravagant, overflowing, gushing, exuberant, expansive, ebullient, free-flowing, unrestrained, talkative, fulsome, profuse, unreserved
***He was effusive in his praise of the General.***

Also,
This [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=effusive%20in%20his%20praise,effusive%20praise&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2008) for *effusive in his praise* and *effusive praise* shows the expressions are on well-trodden territory:
[image]

Comment: was that "the General" or the film "The General"?

Comment: @JoeBlow Collins doesn't even capitalize 'general' http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/effusive No way to know.

Comment: great point, Kris !

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I've never seen "effusive" used negatively. "Gushy", on the other hand, has always implied that it's too much.

Comment: Yes, too much to be positive even.

Comment: perfectly put -- effusive is positive. "gushy" say is when you go too far!  i'm effusive on this answer!

Comment: effusive - Dictionary Definition : Vocabulary.com
www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/effusive
Getting a compliment from your effusive Aunt Sally can be a little embarrassing. Since she's so effusive, Aunt Sally holds nothing back, gushing with enthusiasm.